# How to get the anchor tag value from the string variable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing

```
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td> 1.<a class="mybk" href="/sample/samples/sample.php?mybookid=2000"> PROFESSIONAL EDUCATIONAL</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 2.<a class="mybk" href="/sample/samples/sample.php?mybookid=2001"> New EDUCATIONAL</a></td>
  </tr>
  ........
  .
</table>
```

From the HTML I can able to get the tr, td  value as

```
1.<a class="mybk" href="/sample/samples/sample.php?mybookid=2000"> PROFESSIONAL EDUCATIONAL</a>
```

..etc

my question is on the each row how can i get the anchor tag href value

My code is :

```
$('#mytable> tbody > tr').each(function() { 
 var name = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html();
 var href = $(".mybk").attr('href');
}
```

I got only first href values for all the loop. How can i get each time each row a tag  href value ??

Comment: `var href = $(this).find("td .mybk").attr('href');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change it to working "in context"

```
$('#mytable> tbody > tr').each(function() {
 var tData = $(this).find("td").eq(0);
 var name = tData.html();
 var href = $(".mybk", tData).attr('href');
 var bookId = href.match(/mybookid=(\d+)/)[1];
});
```

http://jsbin.com/lijeq/1/

Comment: Thank you working fine .. need another help how can i get the mybookid value for each tag I used  <pre> var mybkid = href.match(/type\=\d+/)[0].replace(/bookid\=/,''); </pre>  not working says type error

Comment: Can you post is as separate question @subhas?

Answer (score -1):

Because you're asking for that value:

```
var href = $(".mybk").attr('href');
```

IE: the first element with class `.mybk` encountered
try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#mytable> tbody > tr').each(function() { 
     var name = $(this).find("a").text();
     var href = $(this).find("a").attr('href');
     console.log(name,href);
    });
})
```

Comment: So you downvoted my correct answer because you don't got it?? http://jsfiddle.net/j9kcLzvk/4/ it's exactly as the question put it! wre we supposed to make an array?